# How to serve a tensorflow model using docker image tensorflow/serving when there are custom ops?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to use the tf-sentencepiece operation in my model found here https://github.com/google/sentencepiece/tree/master/tensorflow

There is no issue building the model and getting a saved_model.pb file with variables and assets. However, if I try to use the docker image for tensorflow/serving, it says

```
Loading servable: {name: model version: 1} failed: 
Not found: Op type not registered 'SentencepieceEncodeSparse' in binary running on 0ccbcd3998d1. 
Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. 
Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing 
(e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, 
as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
```

I am unfamiliar with how to build anything manually, and was hoping that I could do this without many changes.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to:

1. Pull a docker development image

   $ docker pull tensorflow/serving:latest-devel
2. In the container, make your code changes

   $ docker run -it tensorflow/serving:latest-devel

Modify the code to add the op dependency [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/BUILD#L299).

3. In the container, build TensorFlow Serving

   container:$ tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server && cp bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server /usr/local/bin/
4. Use the exit command to exit the container
5. Look up the container ID:

   $ docker ps
6. Use that container ID to commit the development image:

   $ docker commit  $USER/tf-serving-devel-custom-op
7. Now build a serving container using the development container as the source

   $ mkdir /tmp/tfserving

   $ cd /tmp/tfserving

   $ git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/serving .

   $ docker build -t $USER/tensorflow-serving --build-arg TF_SERVING_BUILD_IMAGE=$USER/tf-serving-devel-custom-op -f tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile .
8. You can now use $USER/tensorflow-serving to serve your image following the [Docker instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/docker#running_a_serving_image)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. We've decided to use a different tf hub module that didn't require a custom op, but I'm sure this will be useful were we to try using the other module again or for other people trying to do this.